# Convert 32 bit uniform distribution to uniform distribution on any int

Tags: hash, language-agnostic, distribution, bit, murmurhash

Given a discrete uniform distribution `D~U([0:2^N-1]` from which a sample yields a number in the inclusive  integer range [`0`, `2^N-1`] for an integer `N`, I need a function `convert` such that for a sample `d~D`, `convert(d, m)` will have an integer uniform inclusive distribution `Dc~U([0:m])`.

---

Thoughts:

- If the distribution is continuous, this is easy. Just cutoff the infinite representation of the number, and the uniformity is preserved.
- I can't think of a way to do this for all numbers and keep uniformity.
- I could re-roll for tie conditions, but am not able to formulate an algorithm.

---

What I eventually want, is a [murmur hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) on a custom range (`m`), rather than exact 32 bit numbers.

Comment: There is a paper how to do that: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.10941.pdf